# Using program in another file gives different output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a rather unique issue with my code that I have not experienced before and could use some guidance.

Here is an attempt a short explanation:

**Basically, I have a program with many functions that are tied to one main one. It takes in data from files sent to it and gives output based on many factors. Running this function in the file itself gives the proper results, however, if I import this function and run it in the main.py, it gives very, *very* incorrect output.**

I am going to do my best to show the least amount of code in this post, so here is the [GitHub.](https://github.com/j-muell/CompSci1026-Assignments/tree/master/Assignment%203) Please use it for further reference and understanding of what is happening. I don't know any websites that I can use to link and run my code for these purposes.

`sentiment_analysis.py` is the file with all of the functions. `main.py` is the file that utilizes it all, and `driver.py` is the file given by my prof to test this assignment.

Basic assignment explanation (*skip if not needed for answering the question*): Take in twitter data from the files given along with keywords that have an associated happiness value. Take all data, split into timezone regions (approximation based on given point values, not real timezones), and then give back basic information about the data in the files. ie. Average happiness per timezone, total keyword tweets, and total tweets, for each region.

Running `sentiment_analysis` will currently give correct output based on heavy testing.
Running `main` and `driver` will give incorrect output. Ex. tweets2 has 25 total lines of twitter data, but using driver will return 91 total tweets and keyword tweets (eastern data, 4th test scenario in driver.py) instead of the expected 15 total tweets in that region.

I've spent about 3 hours testing scenarios and outputting different information to try and debug but have had no luck. If anyone has any idea why it's returning different outputs when called in a different file, that would be great.

The following are the three most important functions in the file, with the first being the one called in another file.

```
def compute_tweets(tweets, keywords):
    try: 
        with open(tweets, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f: # opens the file 
            tweet_list = f.read().splitlines() # reads and splitlines the file. Gets rid of the \n
            print(tweet_list)
        with open(keywords, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
            keyword_dict = {k: int(v) for line in f for k,v in [line.strip().split(',')]}
        # instead of opening this file normally i am using dictionary comprehension to turn the entire file into a dictionary
        # instead of the standard list which would come from using the readlines() function.
        
        determine_timezone(tweet_list) # this will run the function to split all pieces of the file into region specific ones
        eastern = calculations(keyword_dict, eastern_list)
        central = calculations(keyword_dict, central_list)
        mountain = calculations(keyword_dict, mountain_list)
        pacific = calculations(keyword_dict, pacific_list)

        return final_calculation(eastern, central, mountain, pacific)
        

    except FileNotFoundError as excpt:
        empty_list = [] 
        print(excpt)
        print("One or more of the files you entered does not exist.")
        return empty_list
```

```
# Constants for Timezone Detection
    # eastern begin
p1 = [49.189787, -67.444574]
p2 = [24.660845, -67.444574]
    # Central begin, eastern end
p3 = [49.189787, -87.518395]
# p4 = [24.660845, -87.518395]      - Not needed
    # Mountain begin, central end
p5 = [49.189787, -101.998892]
# p6 = [24.660845, -101.998892]     - Not needed
    # Pacific begin, mountain end
p7 = [49.189787, -115.236428]
# p8 = [24.660845, -115.236428]     - Not needed
    # pacific end, still pacific
p9 = [49.189787, -125.242264]
# p10 = [24.660845, -125.242264]

def determine_timezone(tweet_list):
    for index, tweet in enumerate(tweet_list): # takes in index and tweet data and creates a for loop
        long_lat = get_longlat(tweet) # determines the longlat for the tweet that is currently needed to work on
        if float(long_lat[0]) <= float(p1[0]) and float(long_lat[0]) >= float(p2[0]):
            if float(long_lat[1]) <= float(p1[1]) and float(long_lat[1]) > float(p3[1]):
                # this is testing for the eastern region
                eastern_list.append(tweet_list[index])
            elif float(long_lat[1]) <= float(p3[1]) and float(long_lat[1]) > float(p5[1]):
                # testing for the central region
                central_list.append(tweet_list[index])
            elif float(long_lat[1]) <= float(p5[1]) and float(long_lat[1]) > float(p7[1]):
                # testing for mountain region
                mountain_list.append(tweet_list[index])
            elif float(long_lat[1]) <= float(p7[1]) and float(long_lat[1]) >= float(p9[1]):
                # testing for pacific region
                pacific_list.append(tweet_list[index])
            else:
                # if nothing is found, continue to the next element in the tweet data and do nothing
                continue
        else:
            # if nothing is found for the longitude, then also continue
            continue
```

```
def calculations(keyword_dict, tweet_list):
    # - Constants for caclulations and returns
    total_tweets = 0
    total_keyword_tweets = 0
    average_happiness = 0
    happiness_sum = 0

    for entry in tweet_list: # saying for each piece of the tweet list
        word_list = input_splitting(entry) # run through the input splitting for list of words
        total_tweets += 1 # add one to total tweets
        keyword_happened_counter = 0 # this is used to know if the word list has already had a keyword tweet. Needs to be
        # reset to 0 again in this spot.
        for word in word_list:  # for each word in that word list 
            for key, value in keyword_dict.items(): # take the key and respective value for each item in the dict
                # print("key:", key, "val:", value)
                if word == key: # if the word we got is the same as the key value
                    if keyword_happened_counter == 0: # and the keyword counter hasnt gone up
                        total_keyword_tweets += 1 # add one to the total keyword tweets
                        keyword_happened_counter += 1 # then add one to keyword happened counter
                    happiness_sum += value # and, if we have a keyword tweet, no matter what add to the happiness sum
                else:
                    continue # if we don't have a word == key, continue iterating.
    if total_keyword_tweets != 0:
        average_happiness = happiness_sum / total_keyword_tweets # calculation for the average happiness value
    else:
        average_happiness = 0
    return [average_happiness, total_keyword_tweets, total_tweets] # returning a tuple of info in proper order
```

My apologies for the wall of both text and code. I'm new to making posts on here and am trying to include all relevant information... If anyone knows of a better way to do this aside from using github and code blocks, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When calling `compute_tweets(tweets, keywords)` how are those paths passed?

Comment: Each time you call `compute_tweets()` it appends to `eastern_list`, `central_list`, etc. And these persist between calls. So the second call will include all the tweets from the first call, and the third call will include all the tweets from the first two, etc.

Comment: @JonSG It's imported in a separate file, in this case, driver.py and or main.py, where a text file is passed into the compute_tweets function through there. The text file is within the file location. Hopefully this is what you were asking about

Comment: @Barmar so theoretically, the first time I call compute_tweets() it will give the true output, and each time from there on is incorrect because the list is never reset? Meaning the issue would essentially be solved if I redefine the lists each time compute_tweets() is called...? Am i understanding correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You should empty all those lists at the beginning of `compute_tweets`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much - this resolved my issue! Can't believe I missed something so simple. Feel free to throw it in an answer so I can accept it for the post